# Press button from wear and do something on phone

Tags: android, wear-os

I am completely new to this wear stuff.So i want to press a button **from my wear** and do something that a function from my mobile phone class does.Can i use intent or something?I followed this [tutorial](https://www.androidauthority.com/develop-simple-android-wear-app-622043/) but i couldn't manage to send the notifications from mobile to wear as well.

Comment: Can you add more details like what specific errors you've encountered or if there is any?

Comment: @Jacque I just wanted to know if there is any tutorial for android wear and mobile